# No Suitable Method Found To Override - OnConfiguring

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

[image]
[image]
As seen above, I cannot override the onconfiguring method. I see the error No Suitable Method Found To Override.Visual studio doesn't see it. My installed packages are below.

[image]

My Code:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ShopApp.Entities;

namespace ShopApp.DataAccess.Concrete.EfCore
{
public class ShopContext:DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

  }
}
```

Comment: its `internal virtual` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.onconfiguring?view=efcore-6.0

Comment: @Jamiec no, it's `protected internal virtual`, so not sure what point you're getting at?

Comment: Can you confirm that you're using .NET Core 2.2?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar my .net core 3.1

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a good solution but I solved my problem as follows.
I was using .Net Core version 3.1. I solved the problem by downgrading the .Net Core version to 2.1.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Well, you should use the same version of .net core as ef core, so it's a good solution insofar as you want to be stuck on 2.2.  Better of course would be to modernize all of it to the latest version (6.0, soon 7.0).

Comment: I would have suggested trying EF Core version 3.1.26 if your .NET Core version is 3.1.